# How to extract only a specific value from a python sublist that I got as an API response from Monkeylearn

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, sublist, monkeylearn

I have been training a text classification model in Monkeylearn and as a response to my API query, I get a python list as a result. I want to extract only the specific text classification value from it. Attaching the code below.

```
ml = MonkeyLearn('42b2344587')
data = reddittext[2]    # dataset in a python list
model_id = 'cl7C'
result = ml.classifiers.classify(model_id, data)
print(result.body)   #response from API in list format
```

Output I get is :

```
[{'text': 'comment\n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': []},
 {'text': 'So this is the worst series of Kohli like in years.\n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': []}, 
 {'text': 'Saini ODI average at 53 \n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Batting', 'tag_id': 122983950, 'confidence': 0.64}]}]
```

I want to only print the classifications - tag_name ie "Batting" from this list.

```
type(result.body)
```

the output I get is: List

Answer (score 0):

The `result.body` is a list of dicts and text, also known as the JSON format.

You can get the desired information by iterating through the lists with a for-loop and performing dictionary look ups with `d["key"]` if you know the key exists or `d.get("key")` if you don't know whether the key exists in the dictionary. The `get` command will return `None` if the key `tag_name` doesn't exist.

```
for entry in result.body:
    for classification in entry['classifications']:
        tag_name = classification.get('tag_name')
        if tag_name is not None:
            print(tag_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know if response format is fixed or not, assuming it isn't.

Use Json to encode response to string, and use regex to find string.

This way, you can match multiple occurances. Since you're receiving most likely json files, json module won't complain about encoding it.

```
import json
import re


testcase = [{'text': 'comment\n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': []},
            {'text': 'So this is the worst series of Kohli like in years.\n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': []},
            {'text': 'Saini ODI average at 53 \n', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Batting', 'tag_id': 122983950, 'confidence': 0.64}]}]


# if data format is fixed
print(testcase[-1]['classifications'][0]['tag_name'])


# if not, expensive but works.
def json_find(source, key_name):
    json_str = json.dumps(source)
    pattern = f'(?<={key_name}": ")([^,"]*)'
    found = re.findall(pattern, json_str)
    return found

print(json_find(testcase, 'tag_name')[0])
```

Result:

> Batting
>   Batting